# Find the best least square approximation to $h(x)=x^\frac{1}{3}+x^\frac{2}{3}$ by linear fucntion.

Tags: inner-products

Consider the inner product  space

$$C_{[-1,1]}\text{ with inner product :=}\int ^1_{-1} f(x)g(x)dx$$
Let $U=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}x\}$ form  basis for a subspace of C, than

1.Show that $U$ is an orthogonal basis . and

2.Find the best least square approximation to $h(x)=x^\frac{1}{3}+x^\frac{2}{3}$ by linear function.

My attempt  as $\|f\|=\|g\|=1 $ and $<f,g>=0$ than we can say that $U$ is an orthonormal basis

How to solve the second question any hint, please

How to solve

Comment: Once you have an orthonormal basis $f_i$ for a subspace $U$, the least square approximation for $g$ drawn from $U$ is $\sum_i \langle f_i,g \rangle f_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\|f\|=\|g\|=1$ and since $\langle f,g\rangle=0$, $\{f,g\}$ is an orthonormal basis of the space of all first degree polynomials. So, take $\langle h,f\rangle f+\langle h,g\rangle g$.